# Non-CM totally imaginary number fields

Tags: number-theory, algebraic-number-theory

Is there a name for the totally imaginary number fields that are not CM-fields?

Any important subclass of number fields with that property, or perhaps a reference where those field are studied in some detail?

Thanks in advance for any relevant information!

Comment: I might be wrong, but I think every totally imaginary number field is a CM field. To see this, take a totally imaginary number field $K$. We want to find an index 2 totally real subfield. To this end, take a primitive element $x$, which is necessarily nonreal in every embedding. The field generated by $x\bar x$ and $x + \bar x$ will be index two, because the minimal polynomial for $x$ over it will be $t^2 + (x + \bar x)t + x\bar x$ and it is clearly totally real.

Comment: @JordanHardy: It is not clear why a given embedding of $K$ into $\mathbb C$ would contain $\bar x$ with (the image of) $x$. (Unless the field is Galois, it has no reason to be stable under complex conjugation.) Even if that is the case, I do not see why in general a) the polynomial is irreducible b) that subfield would be "clearly" totally real.  ---- (It seems a bit unlikely that CM fields get so much limelight if literally every totally complex field were CM, doesn't it.)

Comment: For an example, let $K$ be the field obtained by adjoining to $\mathbb Q$ a root $\alpha$ of the polynomial $x^4+2$. Calling $\zeta$ a fixed primitive $8$th complex root of unity, and $\sqrt[4]{2}$ the usual positive real number, there are four embeddings $j_i:K \rightarrow \mathbb C$, given by $\alpha \mapsto \zeta^i \sqrt[4]{2}$ for $i=1,3,5,7$. Then $j_1(K) =j_5(K)$ and $j_3(K)=j_7(K)$ because $\zeta = -\zeta^5$ etc., but the conjugate of $j_1$ is $j_3$, and $j_1(K) \cap j_3(K) = \mathbb Q$.

Comment: @TorstenSchoeneberg You're correct.  I was mistaken when I wrote this comment. Thank you for the clarification.

Answer (score -1):

If your field is Galois and non-CM, it will by definition by totally imaginary -- at least in the sense of being non-real in all embeddings. There is nothing like a purely imaginary field, so I guess this is your definition. Therefore saying non-CM and totally imaginary seems to be the same.

Comment: CM means that it's a totally imaginary quadratic extension of a totally real field. In particular, every CM-field is totally imaginary. So not every totally imaginary field is non-CM, but also not every non-CM field is totally imaginary.

Comment: That was precisely my question! WHAT is totally imaginary? I know what CM means. If you read my post, I consider the important case of galois extensions. 
If they are not Kronecker -- thus neither CM nore real, then they are totally imaginary. So if you want some distinction, your fields will not be galois!?

Comment: Totally imaginary, as you correctly say in your answer, means that it doesn't have any real embeddings. But the implication "Galois and non-CM implies totally imaginary" in the first sentence of your answer is still wrong - any totally real Galois extension will give a counterexample.

Comment: Oh no --- come on, let us not come with trivialities. Non CM means of course ALSO not totally real! Or non-Kronecker, if you are so picky! Let us not play with words.

Comment: To me, non-CM simply means "not CM", which doesn't have any clause about not being real, but okay, let's assume we have included that. The last claim in your answer is still not true - according to your definition non-CM does imply totally imaginary, but the converse implication doesn't hold.